# How to get the "(human) Face" position from Webcam Texture

Tags: textures, graphics, camera, face

I am searching a way to recalculate the current Position of the Face in "Virtual World Position" From a Webcam Texture. 
I was thinking about a way to solve this via taking the Average Pupillary distance (which is ~60mm).
And...
With this number I somehow need to get a actual position ... somehow... of the... Face...  (The Center)

I dont know how exactly though.
Any Ideas?

[image: Explaining Image]

Comment: Are you using any existing computer vision libraries, or trying to roll your own solution from scratch? [Having done this myself, I don't recommend it](https://twitter.com/D_M_Gregory/status/460248133604102144) — it's very fiddly, and difficult to match the tracking quality of established solutions. As a starting point, have you read up on face detection and tracking methods and decided which ones you plan to use?

Comment: At the Moment im at very the beginning of my journey.
I thought of getting the coordinates of my eyes from existing assetstore-assets or some Framework. Im not sure there is any need for doing it from scratch right now.

Is there any "easy-to-use-thing" ? 
I only need the coodinates of the eyes.

Comment: My Question here was not for getting ideas for a framework, but how to convert the data from the Textures to Virtual-World-Positions.

Comment: Ah, so you have the 2D coordinates of the eye pixels in image space, and you need the 3D coordinates in a camera-relative real world coordinate space? Do you have access to parameters describing the webcam's projection (field of view / focal length, lens distortion, etc)?